# Xinput monitors key presses but not mouse clicks

Tags: mouse, xinput, xrdp

The `xinput list` command gives me the following output (I access workstation via `xRDP`):

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xrdpMouse                                 id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xrdpKeyboard                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Should I execute `xinput test 7`, it would show scancodes for all the keys I press.

To my surprise `xinput test 6` does show mouse movements, but not button clicks or wheel rotations. Those events pass completely unnoticeable for `xinput`. Can it be remedied? My guess is it has something to do with `xRDP`.

Comment: Try `xinput test-xi2 --root 6`